# Generator for total time spent in the system

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

I know that the generator of the waiting time of a M/G/1 queue, that is, the time spent by a customer before starting service is given by
$$Gf(y)=\lambda \int_0^\infty [f(y+s)-f(y)]dF(s)-f'(y)1(y>0)$$
where $\lambda$ is the arrival rate and $F(s)$ is the cdf of the service time.
Is there a similar generator for the total time spent by a customer, that is waiting time plus the time spent in service. Any reference will be appreciated.

Comment: You just need to add the time being served, which presumably is independent of the time waiting to be served

Comment: I see. But I am more interested in how it will change the generator?

Comment: Presumably, the LHS of the given equation should be $G f(y)$?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes. Sorry about that.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4719476/generator-of-waiting-time-process-in-a-queue